# Time evolution operator with chemical potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, chemical-potential, fluctuation-dissipation

In the Bruus and Flensberg textbook, section 1.5, it is mentioned that

> Basically, the result obtained from the canonical ensemble is carried over to the grand canonical ensemble by the substitution $H \to H - \mu N$, where $N$ is the particle number operator.

Assuming the above, how does the evolution operator for a quantum state look like? For a time-independent Hamiltonian, should it be $\exp(\frac{1}{i\hbar} Ht)$ or $\exp(\frac{1}{i\hbar} (H-\mu N)t)$?

**Edit**

For context, I'm trying to derive the fluctuation-dissipation theorem. Firstly, the definitions are:
\begin{align*}
G^<(t) &= \frac{1}{i\hbar} \langle c_j^\dagger c_i(t) \rangle \\
G^>(t) &= -\frac{1}{i\hbar} \langle c_i(t) c_j^\dagger \rangle \\
G^R(t) &= \frac{1}{i\hbar} \Theta(t) \langle \{ c_i(t), c_j^\dagger \} \rangle \\
G^A(t) &= -\frac{1}{i\hbar} \Theta(-t) \langle \{ c_i(t), c_j^\dagger \} \rangle
\end{align*}

The operators are in the Heisenberg picture, and $c_j^\dagger \equiv c_j^\dagger(0)$ as a shorthand. The expectation value is taken with the grand canonical density matrix.
\begin{align*}
\langle A \rangle = \mathrm{tr} \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta (H -\mu N)} A
\end{align*}

I'm expecting the proof to be as follows
\begin{align*}
-G^<(t + i\hbar \beta) &= e^{\beta \mu} G^>(t) \\
-e^{\beta E} G^<(E) &= e^{\beta \mu} G^>(E)
\end{align*}

The Fourier transform is taken with the convention of $G(E) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty G(t) e^{i E t/ \hbar} dt$. This will then give the FDT.
\begin{align*}
G^R(E) - G^A(E) &= G^>(E) - G^<(E) \\
&= -[e^{\beta(E-\mu)} +1] G^<(E) \\
G^<(E) &= - \frac{1}{1+e^{\beta(E-\mu)}} [ G^R(E) - G^A(E) ]
\end{align*}

If the evolution operator is $U(t) = \exp(\frac{1}{i\hbar} Ht)$, then the result is good.
\begin{align*}
\langle c_j^\dagger c_i(t + i\hbar \beta) \rangle &= \langle c_i(t) e^{\beta \mu N} c_j^\dagger e^{-\beta \mu N} \rangle \\
&= e^{\beta\mu} \langle c_i(t) c_j^\dagger \rangle
\end{align*}

Instead, if $U(t) = \exp(\frac{1}{i\hbar} (H-\mu N)t)$, then I do not get the desired expression.
\begin{align*}
\langle c_j^\dagger c_i(t + i\hbar \beta) \rangle = \langle c_i(t) c_j^\dagger \rangle
\end{align*}

Comment: What choice gives you the time-dependent Schrödinger equation?

Comment: @TobiasFünke I have added some of my thought processes, hoping to get an expert opinion!